# Where is the application to reverse the color of the screen?

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys

In the new version of Ubuntu, I cannot find the application to reverse the color of my screen. It has been in the Ubuntu 10, when I pressed the button <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>,
the color of the whole screen would  be reserved. What's the name of that application.
Can I find it in new version?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### **Compiz method**

Its a Compiz plugin,
Firstly install `ccsm` if you havent already

```
sudo aptitude install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then go to

```
System > Preferences > CompizConfig Settings Manager
```

[image: Opening CCSM]

Tick the plugin `Negative`. If it is not listed, then install the `compiz-plugins` package, and reopen CCSM:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
```

[image: Ticking]

Now it should work
But in Natty, You will face a problem, Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> Brings up the messaging menu
So the key association of the `Negative` Plugin should be reassigned to another combination

To do that:
Click the Name of the `negative` plugin
You should encounter such a page
[image: Negative Plugin]
Click the key combinations and change them to something else
[image: Clicking]
Now it will work

### Non Compiz method

Either you can use

```
magnifier -z 1 -fi
```

or 
`sudo apt-get install xcalib`

 `/usr/bin/xcalib -invert -alter;`

Comment: Anyway to do the above steps without installing CCSM?

Comment: @Oxwivi I think so there is a command backend for Compiz.

Comment: `man compiz` does not say anything about how to enable plugins...

Comment: @Amith kk  It seems that the negative cannot be enabled after I do what mentioned in this post.

Comment: Also, remember to run `sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins` in case you don't have the compiz-plugins package already installed for some reason.