# xcalib -inver -alter does not work with the NVIDIA driver version 364

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, screen, xcalib

I have been using `xcalib -invert -alter` to reverse the colors in my screen. The command works fine with the nouveau driver using the onboard graphics driver. However, when I switch to NVIDIA binary driver version 364, the screen color is not inverted.

My laptop is ASUS ROG-GL552VW. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M. If any additional information is useful to fix my problem, I'd be glad to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I wasn't able to make `xcalib` work. Instead, I installed [CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/) as instructed in the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56772/where-is-the-application-to-reverse-the-color-of-the-screen) and started using the shortcuts in **CompizConfig Settings Manager -> Accesibility -> Negative**. If you cannot see the **Negative** option, you have to install **compiz-plugins**:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be an alternative way. I've Ubuntu 16.04, Dell E6410, NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [NVS 3100M], nvidia driver 340.98. This works fine:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --brightness -1
```

Check for connection name and brightness support using `xrandr --verbose`

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2720 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 connected 1440x900+1280+0 (0x250) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 370mm x 230mm
    Identifier: 0x24c
    Timestamp:  14126803
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    ...
```

Comment: Interesting answer; never heard of `--brightness -1`. Thank you!